# startActivity not working even after adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, android-intent, task, android-context

My app has a `share` class to share files. After upgrading from target 27 to target 29, it stop working with an `AndroidRuntimeException`:

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

So I added the flag, yet I still get the exact same error.
Why am I getting the error even after I set the flag? I have no `android:launchMode` in the Manifest file.

This is the method with the flag already added:

```
public class Share {
  public static void sharefile(Context context, String filename) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (getUriFromFile(new File(filename)));
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, filename);
    sharingIntent.setType((new FileChooser()).getMimeType(filename));
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, filename));
}
```

This is how it is called:

```
   Share.sharefile(getApplicationContext(), filename);
```

Comment: Instead of passing the application context, pass the activity context in which you are calling this share method.

Comment: Indeed, this prevents the error, THANKS!! However, I got another one (without actual crash): `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://<filename> from pid=25134, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`